# Excel VBA talk to 2 Powerpoint presentations

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

Within Excel VBA I want to write out data to two PowerPoint presentations, can anyone point me in the right direction with some code? I can get it to work find with one presentation but not two at the same time.

Any help appreciated!

Pseudo code:

```
Open PP1
Open PP2

for i = 1 to 10
    do some calcs in excel
    create new slide in PP1 and add data
    create new slide in PP2 and add data
loop

Close PP1
Close PP2
```

Comment: Can you show your 'real' code for the working single presentation?

Answer (score 0):

As @PortlandRunner says, it'd be better to show us the code you've got already.

But in general, you'd:

Dim two variables as Object or Presentation, depending on whether you prefer late or early binding, let's say oPres1 and oPres2

```
Set oPres1 = oPPTObject.Presentations.Open("C:\some\folder\SomePresentation.pptx")
Set oPres2 = oPPTObject.Presentations.Open("C:\some\folder\SomeOTHERPresentation.pptx")

With oPres1
   ' Do stuff
End With
With oPres2
   ' Do Stuff
End With
```

Close both presentations